# Upgraded Android Studio, now I'm getting the message "Could not find property 'compile'..." related to my project gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

The message is

```
Error:(27, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@64d9a7e6.   
Open File
```

When I press `Open file` I'm taken to my `build.gradle` for my project, and I think it's trying to show me my dependancies. Here is what that page looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myname.myappname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def var = dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' compile
    'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2' compile
    'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1' compile
    'com.android.support:design:24.1.1' compile
    'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.yayandroid:LocationManager:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

Also, `var` (from `def var = dependancies`) is greyed out and it says "assignment not used" when I mouse over it, though I don't know if this is related. I was using a version from a year ago or so, but I'm able to use some of my other projects in the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def var = dependencies {` seems to be nonsense, it should simply be `dependencies {`, this is no error though, just nonsense.

I think your problem is shifted newlines. The whole block

```
def var = dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' compile
    'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2' compile
    'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1' compile
    'com.android.support:design:24.1.1' compile
    'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.yayandroid:LocationManager:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

should probably be

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.yayandroid:LocationManager:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

and everything should work again.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the gradle error but it turned out I had all kinds of issues with the code in the project, and I have no idea where they came from. Luckily I redownloaded the project from github and it worked fine, dunno what happened to that one.